# Determining where / if line intersects triangle in 3D space

Tags: c#, vb.net, opengl, math, opentk

**Problem**

So basically I have a bunch of triangles that are defined by 3 points:

```
X0, Y0, Z0
X1, Y1, Z1
X2, Y2, Z2
```

I have two points that form a line:

```
Xl0, Yl0, Zl0
Xl1, Yl1, Zl1
```

I have a point in space (P) defined as:

```
Xp0, Yp0, Zp0
```

[image]

I want to know first, how can I determine an equation of the line that is parallel with the original line, but goes through my new point P?

Secondly, using that new line, how can I determine if and where on my triangle it intersects?

I would like to try and create a function that takes the inputs that I have presented and outputs a point which is the intersection of the triangle and a boolean value if it did intersect.

Now I would like to do this through c# or VB .NET but the actual solution really is just math based so answers that are expressed as math and not code would definitely help too.

**What I have tried**

I thought that calculating the new line would simply be the new point and a second point where

```
Xnew = Xl0 + (Xp0 - Xl1)
Ynew = Yl0 + (Yp0 - Yp1)
Znew = Zl0 + (Zp0 - Zp1)
```

then plotting the new line from (Xnew, Ynew, Znew) to (Xp0, Yp0, Zp0) should be a parallel line to my first one, however in doing so they are not parallel which means my calculation is wrong.

Any help would be **greatly** appreciated!

**Update**

After trying what was suggested below, the line that is drawn doesn't seem to be correct yet:

[image]

The camera's location to the origin is what creates the first line.
The second line that we determined is the line from our cursor location, to the new calculated point which should be parallel to the line that goes from the origin to the camera, which as you see is not the case.  Am I wrong in my thought process or am I not coding it correctly?

My code doing the calculation like suggested below:

```
GL.Begin(PrimitiveType.Lines)
    GL.Color3(Color.Orange)

    Dim XL0, YL0, ZL0 As Single
    XL0 = 0
    YL0 = 0
    ZL0 = 0

    'origin is at 0,0,0

    Dim XL1, YL1, ZL1 As Single
    XL1 = camx
    YL1 = camy
    ZL1 = camz

    Dim XS, YS, ZS As Single

    XS = XL1 - XL0
    YS = YL1 - YL0
    ZS = ZL1 - ZL0

    Dim length As Single = Sqrt(XS * XS + YS * YS + ZS * ZS)

    XS /= length
    YS /= length
    ZS /= length

    Dim XPN, YPN, ZPN As Single

    XPN = returnvec.X - XS * length
    YPN = returnvec.Y - YS * length
    ZPN = returnvec.Z - ZS * length


    GL.Vertex3(XPN, YPN, ZPN)
    GL.Vertex3(returnvec.X, returnvec.Y, returnvec.Z)
    GL.End()
```

[image]

Trial 1

[image]

Trial 2

Comment: Where are Yp1 and Zp1 defined?

Comment: If you need help with the math maybe you should start on http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Your equation for finding the second point is correct.  You must have an error in the way you've coded it up, or the way you're plotting the results.

Comment: @Darryl I have updated my question to show my code. Something still seems off. Any suggestions?

Comment: Take a look at a set of concrete values for a particular pass through this code.  Are the two resulting lines mathematically parallel?  Forget the graphics for now, just check it mathematically.

Comment: You can break this down into multiple steps: (A) determine the equation of a plane from 3 points on the plane (B) determine the intersection of a plane and a line (C) determine whether the point falls inside the triangle.

Comment: @Darryl My new line and my old line are NOT parallel. See Trial 2.  Where am I messing up for the math?

Comment: @Darryl - After tweeking my formulas I got it so my X, Y, and Z slopes are all equal. Length is the same for both too.  The display ends up looking like Trial 1 above. Does this mean that something is wrong with how I am displaying it?

Comment: @BenVoigt I agree but am struggling with finding the line first

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I drew the lines and they are indeed parallel. I think what is happening is that since I am viewing the line as a perspective view, it appears to converge inward. That means that my math for creating a parallel line is correct which is technically my question. The parallel line however is not what I need to do ray casting.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to know first, how can I determine an equation of the line that
>   is parallel with the original line, but goes through my new point P?

To get the slope of your line:

```
XS = XL1 - XL0;
YS = YL1 - YL0;
ZS = ZL1 - ZL0;
// Find length of new slope
length = Math.Sqrt(XS * XS + YS * YS + ZS * ZS);
// Normalize the new slope
XS /= length;
YS /= length;
ZS /= length;
```

Now `XS` is a `Vector3` which basically represents the slope of your line, you can do the same with another line and you can test by comparing that slope to this one, and reverse slope to this one as well.

Now if you want to create a new line with this slope, and find a point `N` from a point `P` and a `length` we do:

```
XPN = XPP + XS * length;
YPN = YPP + YS * length;
ZPN = ZPP + ZS * length;
```

Comment: That answers the first question. Any suggestion for the second question?

Comment: unfortunately not, that is something i would like to figure out as well, the math for that gets very complicated

Comment: I tried out what you said, and what makes sense to me as well but the result is not a parallel line. Please see my update to my question.

Comment: what do you get from it?

Comment: no, like if its not a parallel line i am curious as to what it is? is it random? not parallel but consistent?

Comment: Ohh! its flipped! either subtract `L1` from `L0` instead or use the negative slope, i.e. `-XS, -YS, -ZS`

Comment: I updated the gif in my question again.. Seems to still be off. The angle is too sharp, aiming more at the origin than being parallel

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90449/discussion-between-lolslowsti-and-eric-f).